# How to make pop up div locked to the page coordinates in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

On Stack Overflow page, most pop up divs are "glued" to current page coordinates, so if you scroll the screen up/down, popup window remain glued to the clicked element. How can I achive that?

What I have currently is than when I click on the button, popup appears, but when I scroll the page up/down, element remains glued to the window screen, and not page coordinates. How can I get it to work Stack Overflow way, so the pop up div will be glued to page coordinates?

My current code for that element is

`$(".userinfo").offset({ top: position.top + 60, left: position.left});`

css position of the div is obviously absolute

Comment: can you create a fiddle if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you append your popup div to the main html window, hence it behaves like position:fixed. If you want your popup to be, as you said, 'glued' to the button position, you need to append it within your `<div class="button">` (or whatever you are having) element.

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="button">
        <div class="userinfo></div> // Here's where you need to put your '.userinfo' class in
    </div>
</div>
```

and jQ:

```
$('.userinfo-main').appendTo('div.button');
```

This will make it positioned within your `<div class="button">` and therefore 'glued' to it's coordinates, not to main screen.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use position: inherit

For example see
http://jsfiddle.net/djlancejordan/g4p3phwz/

```
$(document).click('show', function() {
   $('.hide').removeClass('hide').css(position, inherit);    
});
```